# How to Lock Google sheet at a particular time in a day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-gsuite

I need to lock google sheet every day at 5 PM to 6 PM to read-only mode. do we have a setting to achieve this? I saw a couple of answers in StackOverflow but most of them are to lock cells

I followed the below script and created a time-driven trigger. it says Execution complete. But I can still write into my sheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //INSERT SHEET NAME HERE

function lockRanges() {
  //First cell to lock
  var row = 1;
  var col = 1;

  // Get last row with data in sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Loop until last row in sheet is passed
  while(row <= lastRow){
    //Lock current cell
    lockRange(row, col);

    // Go to row 7 steps down from current (the next date)
    row = row + 7;
  }
}



function lockRange(row, col){
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);

  // Create protection object. Set description, anything you like.
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected, row ' + row);

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a more descriptive details of your search efforts (include links, add a [mcve])  as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Try logging in as another user on another browser and see if the sheet is protected from other users.  I don't use protection much but I suspect that  you probably can't protect it from yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with 2 triggers.